# How to call stored procedure which updates values of an SqlTable from java

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table in sql with the following attributes

```
create table Product(
ID int identity primary key not null,
Name nvarchar(50) not null,
Price float not null
)
```

I created a stored procedure to insert values:

```
create proc spInsertNewProduct(
@name nvarchar(50),
@price float,
@qty int)
as
begin 
insert into Product values (@name,@price,@qty)
end
```

I call this method from java like this:

```
public static void insertNewProduct(Product p){
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    String SPsql = "exec[spInsertNewProduct] ?,?,?";
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SPsql);      
        ps.setEscapeProcessing(true);
        ps.setString(1, p.getProductName());
        System.out.println(p.getProductName());
        ps.setDouble(2, p.getPrice());
        System.out.println(p.getPrice());
        ps.setInt(3,p.getQty());
        System.out.println(p.getQty());
        ps.execute();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Then I have this stored procedure which updates the values of an existing object

```
create proc spUpdateProduct(
@id int,
@name nvarchar(50),
@price float,
@qty int)
as
begin
update Product
set Name = @name, Price = @price , Qty = @qty
where ID = @id
end
```

I tried to call this procedure from java and but i get this error: `The index 0 is out of range.` The topics on web haven't helped me very much. This the code for my update method.

```
    public static void updateProduct(Product p){
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    String SPsql = "spUpdateProduct ?,?,?,?";
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SPsql);      
        ps.setEscapeProcessing(true);
        ps.setInt(0, p.getProductId());
        ps.setString(1,p.getProductName());
        ps.setDouble(2, p.getPrice());
        ps.setInt(3,p.getQty());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter index starts at 1 not 0:

```
    ps.setInt(1, p.getProductId());
    ps.setString(2,p.getProductName());
    ps.setDouble(3, p.getPrice());
    ps.setInt(4,p.getQty());
```